# ArrayList entry size return

Tags: java, object, arraylist, size

I am getting error in `ArrayList.size()` return.

#### My code

```
public class College
{
    Student s = new Student();
    ArrayList <Student> entries;

    public College() {
        entries = new ArrayList<Student>();
    }

    public int getSize() {
        return entires.size();
    }
}
```

#### The error

```
College.java:21: error: cannot find symbol
    return entires.size();
                   ^
symbol:   variable entires
location: class College
```

What is this error? can anyone help me?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Typo........... Please pay attention.

Comment: Finally a good reason to close "This question was caused by a problem that can no longer be reproduced **or a simple typographical**."

Answer (score 0, accepted):

That error means that the compiler could not find `entires.size();`

the reason for this is that your arraylist is called something else; `entries`

now when the compiler ran it could not recognize `entires.size();` as a method and threw an error at you.

Answer (score 0):

```
public int getSize()
{
    return entries.size(); //you had a typo here
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You have a typo there. Name of your attribute is `entries` while in your `getSize` method you have `entires`.

The compiler therefore tells you it can't find anything with name `entires`.

Answer (score 0):

There is a typo error.

It should be

```
public class College
{
Student s = new Student();
ArrayList <Student> entries;
public College()
{
    entries = new ArrayList<Student>();
}
    public int getSize()
{
    return entries.size();
}
```